# Sidekiq is very slow at processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, redis, sidekiq

I recently migrated to another, more powerful server.

Upgraded Ruby version, Rails, Sidekiq and Redis but for some unknown to me reason, Sidekiq is incredibly slow at processing tasks.

Sometimes tasks can be staying in "Busy" queue for up to 20 minutes, when in reality, performing same tasks synchronously (via WorkerName.new.perform) take no longer than 10 seconds.

We don't have any long polling tasks longer than 1 minute.

Sidekiq utilizes only one CPU at 100% but I suppose that's normal with MRI. But again, we used to have a much better performance with similar configuration.

config/sidekiq.yml

```
:verbose: false
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:concurrency:  50
:queues:
  - [webmaster_balance, 5]
  - [advertiser_balance, 4]
  - [balance_history, 3]
  - [mailer, 2]
  - [default, 1]
```

We use Capistrano to deploy and capistrano-sidekiq gem.
This is the command that is used to start Sidekiq

`/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /home/deployer/fruby/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid --environment production --logfile /home/deployer/fruby/shared/log/sidekiq.log --config /home/deployer/fruby/current/config/sidekiq.yml --daemon`

Nothing interesting in Sidekiq logs.

- Sidekiq v 3.4.2
- Ruby 2.1.6
- Rails 3.2.22
- Redis Server 3.0.3

Any hints on where should I start looking would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming that your Sidekiq use the database? If so, what's the pool size in your `config/database.yml`? It needs to be high enough to handle all the connections from your rails app *and* your 50 sidekiq threads.

Comment: Pool size is 150. More than enough to handle Sidekiq threads. Again, same configuration was on old server.

Comment: I tried to move from `resque` to `sidekiq` recently with the exact same config as you but I faced incredibly poor performance too. Sorry I can't really help because all I did is rollback to `resque`, I'm just saying you're not the only one

Comment: Are you CPU bound or I/O bound?  How many Sidekiq processes are you running?  If you are only running one with 50 threads, you should try 2 processes with 25 threads.

Comment: Pretty sure I am CPU bound. I am running 1 Sidekiq process. Unfortunately I will be able to try running multiple Sidekiq processes only on Monday and will let you know on my results then. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: So, I did what you suggested. 2 processes with 25 threads each BUT it didn't seem to improve situation much. See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/gHJnyZv.jpg tasks that take in reality 10 seconds take up to 30 minutes. They eventually disappear one by one but take really long to complete.

Comment: @jazzytomato I got the same problem, did migrate back to resque resolve the issue?

Comment: @eugene this thread is a bit old and I don't recall I am sorry. I know that in the end I managed to use sidekiq which is more performant with the appropriate configuration. There are many factors that could cause a problem and I suggest you ask a question with your specific configuration, what problem you observe etc... I suppose that "Migrating back to resque" would not solve the problem that originally makes you want to migrate away from it.

Comment: @jazzytomato thank you for responding me, I faced a very specific case that I have 10 instances (each instance run 3 sidekiq concurrency) and all of them connect to 1 postgresql database. And in this case the query is too slow (from 2ms to 200ms) and I don't have any idea why,  not sure it's accepted as a question in SO.